# Standard log locations for a cross platform application

Tags: linux, windows, macos, logging

I'm developing a cross-platform desktop application for Mac, Linux and Windows. The application will create a plain-text log file to help with debugging, amongst other things. What are people's recommendations for a sensible place to store the log on each of the platforms?

Here is my guess so far, based on web searches:

- Mac: `~/Library/Logs/MY-APP-NAME/system.log`
- Linux: `~/.MY-APP-NAME/logs/system.log`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%\MY-APP-NAME\logs\system.log`

Comment: Is it a system service or something individual logged in users would run interactively?

Comment: In answer to the question from @FlorianWeimer , this is an interactive desktop application run by individually logged-in users.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is followed by some applications.  Log files are not specifically called out as such.  You can put them either into a subdirectory of the data directory (`$XDG_DATA_HOME` or `$HOME/.local/share`), where they will not be deleted automatically, or you could use a subdirectory of the cache directory (`$XDG_CACHE` or `$HOME/.cache`).  In the latter case, the files could be automatically expired after some time.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting.  `$HOME/.local/share` sounds like a good bet to me from your description.  However on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 I don't see data or logs for other applications there. It has a handful of subdirectories including the promising `applications` which is empty.